# Question for use CIAttributedTextImageGenerator draw Text in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-image, cifilter

Sample Code:

```
    NSAttributedString *text = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world" attributes:@{
        NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:100],
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]
    }];
    CIFilter *textGenerator = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIAttributedTextImageGenerator"
                                           keysAndValues: @"inputText", text,nil];
    CIImage *image= [textGenerator valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
```

When I change text's color for the same text, like [UIColor blueColor], and filter again.I'm get the old text texture with redColor.

And I find that unless change the text content to other (get right texture) or scale the texture(have wrong display switch with old and new texture).

It's a diff bug or CIAttributedTextImageGenerator feature...？

How can i get the right texture...?

Only can use it as a basic texture, and render color use other CIFilter?

Or have other way fast render text?

Thanks!!!

I write a simple demo code like this:

```
NSAttributedString *firstText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"
                                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:100],
                                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];
CIFilter *textGenerator1 = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIAttributedTextImageGenerator"
                                     keysAndValues: @"inputText", firstText,nil];
CIImage *texture1= [textGenerator1 valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
self.firstImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:texture1];

NSAttributedString *secondText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"
                                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:100],
                                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]}];
CIFilter *textGenerator2 = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIAttributedTextImageGenerator"
                                     keysAndValues: @"inputText", secondText,nil];
CIImage *texture2= [textGenerator2 valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
self.secondImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:texture2];
```

Display result:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/NABBu.png][1]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please show the code where you change the color and filter again?

Comment: Just run it again and change the color...

Comment: Huh, very interesting... There seem to be some hidden state that is not reset correctly. It seems to be a bug in Core Image. You should probably file a radar for that.

Comment: emm... I think so... whatever thanks for you help!

Comment: A possible workaround might be to blend the text with a solid color image. If you want I can post some code for that.

Comment: You are right. It may use in simple station，if we only need fill text color, can use color filters like CIColorClamp to remap color. Or as you say, create a color texture and use CIBlendWithMask filter to mask with a text texture. When we need add more attributes to text, like stroke, shadow or fill patterns...Then we should get content mask, stroke mask and process for them...